# agsXMPP error in Xamarin mobile app c#

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xmpp

I'm developing one app for android in Xamarin with agsXMPP. But the error is ocurred:

> Error 1   Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 863 2   Chat_MyWork

Answer (score 0):

agsXMPP does not run on Xamarin Android without modifications.
You have to make changes in the sources and remove the reference to System.Drawing to get it running on Xamarin Android.

Or use another c# XMPP library which was already ported to Xamarin Android, or work there without modifications.

Comment: Alex, what would be changes?

Comment: I don't know. Have not tried yet to compile agsXMPP yet for Xamarin.